# How can i set a certain payment option to be blocked when delivery address is different

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, payment-methods

Would it be possible to not show a certain payment method when a customer uses a delivery address different from the billing address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create event listener for payment_method_is_active:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <company_modulename>
                        <class>company_modulename/observer</class>
                        <method>restrictPayments</method>
                    </company_modulename>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and then in the observer to check for:

```
class Company_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function restrictPayments($observer)
    {
        if ($observer->getEvent()->hasQuote()) {
            if (!$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling() && $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'cashondelivery') { //change cashondelivery with whatever payment method you like
                $observer->getEvent()->getResult()->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this... what file do i have to put this? This is all new to me as 1st time magento user so ;-)

Comment: You can read this - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/ or search other article for creating a module.